# Topology of network from adjacency matrix : honeycomb?

Tags: graph-theory, integer-lattices

In a percolative problem, I have noticed that all of the nodes of my system are connected to 3 other nodes. I started drawing a bit and realized that this could look like a honeycomb lattice.

The adjacency matrix is built by assigning the labels $i\in{0,...,n}$ to each node, with $n$ the number of nodes, and assigning $A_{ij} = 1$ if $i$ and $j$ are connected and 0 otherwise.

In my case the adjacency matrix has 3 1's on every line (and is symmetric by definition).

**My question is :** What properties should the adjacency matrix possess to truly represent the topology of a honeycomb lattice ? Is the fact that the sum of all its columns/lines = 3 enough ? Should I be able to tell something about the spectrum of its eigenvalues ?

All input appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem enough as shown by the following graph:
$$\left(\begin{matrix} 
0&1&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
1&0&1&1&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\
1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
1&1&0&0&1&0&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&1&1&0&1&0&0&0&0 \\
0&0&0&0&1&0&1&0&0&1 \\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&1&0 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&1 \\
0&0&0&0&0&0&1&1&0&1 \\
0&0&0&0&0&1&0&1&1&0 \\
 \end{matrix}\right) $$

Comment: I do not see why I cannot reduce this to a honeycomb lattice

Comment: @Mathusalem Hum, may be I get what exactly is a honeycomb lattice. Can you give me a definition (or a link)?

Comment: https://www.google.ch/search?q=honeycomb+lattice&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiU-5uTmr3KAhVCXhQKHaooBHUQ_AUIBygB&biw=967&bih=531#imgrc=kiM8Zf89qXH5CM%3A

Comment: @Mathusalem Then may be I don't get what you mean by reduce ... Because I don't see how the graph I presented to you is similar to the picture you gave me ... I mean 123 form a triangle, 2345 from a rectangle I don't see any hexagons there ...

Comment: I am wondering whether you can twist/move disentagle the points to form such a lattice. I am not saying you are wrong. Anyway I am more and more convinced that the criterion is not sufficient for describing a honeycomb lattice, so I'm wondering what constitutes a hexagonal lattice at an adjacency-matrix level.

Comment: @Mathusalem Ok, so I think the matrix I gave you is a counter example. And actually the clique with 4 nodes is also a counter example.